# What's the best way to 'split' this layer (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, splitting, multi-polygon

[image: map view of single layer I want to seperate]

I'm quite new to all this.

I have this polygon (MultiPolygon) which represents two areas (being visually separate), and now I want to split it so I have two polygons representing two different areas.
My overall aim here is simply to compare the proportion of different colours between the two areas.

So, is there a way to separate this layer?

I looked at the split tool but it doesn't seem to 'split' a layer as I would have hoped unless I have overlooked something.

Another option I thought of was duplicating the original polygon then somehow deleting one of the areas from each so I'm left with two polygons, each showing a different area. However I haven't found a way to simply remove part of a layer either.

Is it possible?

Are either of these options or is there another way I can split this polygon?

Comment: If you create an outline of Area 1 and Area 2, you could use those to Clip your polygons to each study area. https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip

Comment: We need more information to really help. Like you said it's MultiPolygon but do that mean that each color is a single multipart polygon ie, there are only 4 line in the attribute table ? does your polygon overlap or not ?

Comment: The suggestion from @lambertj seems to have worked, thanks very much!

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 4):

You can select and Export selected features as two new layers:

[image]